# Place WinForm On Bottom-Right

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I place a form at the bottom-right of the screen when it loads using C#?

Comment: Related post -[Form position on lower right corner of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15188939/465053)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

try something on the lines of

```
Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width, 
                          workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
```

Hope it works well for you.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for this, I wish I could accept this as the answer :p

Comment: Different monitors,run in different positions

Answer (score 18):

```
Form2 a = new Form2();
a.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
a.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - a.Width, 
                       Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - a.Height);
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me; i just put this code listed below after my `InitializeComponent();`

```
public FormProgress()
{
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to try;

```
//Get screen resolution
Rectangle res = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds; 

// Calculate location (etc. 1366 Width - form size...)
this.Location = new Point(res.Width - Size.Width, res.Height - Size.Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you form constructor put the following code:

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

This will set the start position of the form to whatever you set as the value for the form's location (you can set this in the form designer).

Comment: Problem with this is that everybody use different size screens, it might look fine on yours but it not to say it will on a customers...

Comment: +1 - Yeah, I guess you'd need that one as well, to make the form use the location you specify.