# resize and center form to 80% of screen

Tags: .net, winforms, screen, window-resize

I need to resize my form and make it occupy 80% of the screen, currently, this is what i have

```
 Dim Sw As Integer = CInt(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * 0.8)
        Dim Sh As Integer = CInt(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 0.8)
        Dim nTaskBarHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom
        Me.Size = New Size(Sw, Sh - nTaskBarHeight)
```

But it does not center, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

```
Dim Sw As Integer = CInt(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 0.8)
Dim Sh As Integer = CInt(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * 0.8)
Me.Size = New Size(Sw, Sh)
Dim x As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width \ 2 - Me.Width \ 2
Dim y As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height \ 2 - Me.Height \ 2
Me.Location = New Point(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing only Size;
change Me.Location too; still need do some math for it :)

similar question with great answer:
[Position form at the bottom right corner of the screen in visual basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846352/how-to-position-form-at-the-bottom-right-corner-of-the-screen-in-visual-basic)

Comment: thanks for that, it gave me an idea of what i really needed to do