# Form position on lower right corner of the screen

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, position

I am using c# WinForm to develop a sman notification app. I would like to place the main form on the lower right corner of the screen working area.
In case of multiple screens, there is a way to find the rightmost screen where to place the app, or at least remember the last used screen and palce the form on its lower right corner?

Comment: Related post - [Place WinForm On Bottom-Right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1385674/465053)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't currently have multiple displays to check, but it should be something like

```
    public partial class LowerRightForm : Form
    {
        public LowerRightForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            PlaceLowerRight();
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        private void PlaceLowerRight()
        {
            //Determine "rightmost" screen
            Screen rightmost = Screen.AllScreens[0];
            foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
            {
                if (screen.WorkingArea.Right > rightmost.WorkingArea.Right)
                    rightmost = screen;
            }

            this.Left = rightmost.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
            this.Top = rightmost.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or `var rightmost = Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy (s => s.WorkingArea.Right).Last();`

Comment: @GertArnold I know MoreLINQ has `MaxBy` to be most efficient but if I have to hazard a guess `OrderByDescending.First` should be more efficient than `OrderBy.Last`.

Answer (score 9):

Override the Form `Onload` and set the new location :

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    var screen = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
    this.Location = new Point(screen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width, screen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height);
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Get screen resolution
Rectangle res = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds; 

// Calculate location (etc. 1366 Width - form size...)
this.Location = new Point(res.Width - Size.Width, res.Height - Size.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
    int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;

    // Add this for the real edge of the screen:
    x = 0; // for Left Border or Get the screen Dimension to set it on the Right

    this.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

This following code should work :)

```
var rec = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
int margain = 10;

this.Location = new Point(rec.Width - (this.Width + margain), rec.Height - (this.Height + margain));
```