# How do I start C# program without the window being active?

Tags: c#, window, active-window

I'm trying to create a C# program, but I don't want the window to be active when I open it. I'd like it to open in the background, and the window to show up on top of my other programs, except I want my active window to stay the same. It's because I'm using full screen programs, and I don't want my little popup to take my out of the full screen mode.

Program Use (might help in understanding what I need): I'm creating a set of macros that turn a spare mouse into a media controller. The scroll wheel controls volume, left button controls play/pause, etc. I use Spotify for music, and I want to be able to change the volume of Spotify independently from my computer's global volume. I already have this figured out using code [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/9nwlzd/global_hotkeys_for_spotify/). I want a popup to display telling me that when I use the scroll wheel, I'm changing the volume of Spotify opposed to global volume. I want to be able to activate the macro, display the popup, change the volume as I wish, and then deactivate the macro without exiting my full screen applications. Hopefully this helps, thank you!

Program Use Edit: Here's just an explanation video, should be easier than trying to explain. To clarify, I want the program to not change activated window when it starts and to always be top most, without me having to activate it first. Thank you!!! https://streamable.com/2pewz

I'm using a program called QuickMacros to open the popup and I've tried a few different settings in there but haven't had any luck. I don't have any experience with C#, so I haven't tried anything inside C#.

My code is unrelated to the issue, but here it is just in case. All this does is give me the ability to move the popup.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SpotifyPopup
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.Left += e.X - lastPoint.X;
                this.Top += e.Y - lastPoint.Y;
            }
        }
        Point lastPoint;
        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.Left += e.X - lastPoint2.X;
                this.Top += e.Y - lastPoint2.Y;
            }
        }
        Point lastPoint2;
        private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lastPoint2 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }

        }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear but if I am right what you want is to start your application in minimized state, to do that simply use code below in your form constructor

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

And when your event is fired and you want your app to be on top just use

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

and for proper positioning of your form you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385691/5552166)

### Edit

Ok, now your needs are more clear, this a demo of what i think you want, in this example the form starts minimized and comes to top on mouse wheel, and then goes to background when idle, u can add more events to code and adapt it for your needs,
I used global hooks for this demo thanks to [this link](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook), so dont forget to add the proper nuget package based on the provided link.
here is the code:

```
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private Timer timer;
    private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        Subscribe();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        // Set up how the form should be displayed.
        ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
        Text = "Notify Icon Example";

        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
        Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width - 100,
                                  workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height - 100);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        TopMost = false;
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead
        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();

        m_GlobalHook.MouseWheel += M_GlobalHook_MouseWheel;
    }

    private void M_GlobalHook_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        TopMost = true;
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt -= M_GlobalHook_MouseWheel;

        //It is recommened to dispose it
        m_GlobalHook.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I had some luck with the minimized window state, but the top most part didn't seem to work. The window starts up minimized, but doesn't display anything until it's clicked on.

Comment: @KPopOG, I edited my answer have a look if it helps.

Comment: A bit... let me add in some context in my original post on the project's goals, and that might be a little more helpful. I didn't want to add in too much unnecessary reading but might help you.

Comment: Alright, I'm done. Adding in some more information, hopefully it's useful. Thank you!

Comment: I've been messing around with what you suggested some more, but no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: @KPopOG,have a look and let me know it helps.

Comment: Ah! That's so close. I feel awful for having you do all this work... I'll go in a little more detail... editing the original post.

Comment: @KPopOG, dont feel that way, I enjoy helping and I learn through it, I saw video, still im not sure i got it, so u just want it to always be on top from the moment it starts?, ok so start window in `Normal` state instead of `Minimized` and let `TopMost = true`  do the job, if this is not what you want, plz run the demo code I sent and tell exactly what behavior should be changed, if you think there is lot to explain, maybe we can contact via `skype` find the question and answer and edit ours in here for others reference.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look here: [Bring a window to the front in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257587/bring-a-window-to-the-front-in-wpf)

This thread discusses the general mechanism of presenting, activating and showing windows with WPF.

Comment: The OP is talking about winforms, not WPF